# What is the right sequence to start VMX root operation in Linux

Tags: linux, x86, virtualization

I am working on a Linux kernel module (KVM and KVM_intel have already been unloaded) to test Intel's VMX function.
And now I am wondering the pre-requisite of entering VMX root mode.
My kernel modules uses Linux file system interface to provide a device interface to user space program to do VMX operations.
Here is the code for reference (it was from https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~cruse/cs686s07/nmiexits.c, and changed to work with my Linux-2.6.32, and other needed files were also from that link)

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
//    nmiexits.c    (A modification of our 'linuxvmm.c' module)
//
//    This Linux kernel module implements a device-driver (named
//    '/dev/vmm') which lets an application program execute some
//    real-mode code in Virtual-8086 mode within a guest virtual
//    machine, assuming the cpu supports Intel VMX instructions.
//
//    This modification sets the pin-based VM Execution Controls
//    so that control passes to our Virtual Machine Manager when
//    any external interrupt (or non-maskable interrupt) occurs.
//    These asynchronous events are then serviced by Linux ISRs,
//    and our guest VM is resumed.  For the case of non-maskable
//    interrupts, the host executes the 'int $0x02' instruction;
//    for the case of external interrupts, the appropriate Linux
//    interrupt service routine automatically gets executed when
//    the host executes 'sti', which allows the CPU to recognize
//    the still-pending external interrupt-request.
//
//        compile using:  $ mmake nmiexits
//        install using:  $ /sbin/insmod nmiexits.ko
//
//    NOTE: Written and tested using Linux x86_64 kernel 2.6.17.
//
//    programmer: ALLAN CRUSE
//    date begun: 29 APR 2007
//    completion: 03 MAY 2007    -- our initial driver-prototype
//    revised on: 14 MAY 2007 -- sets 'interrupt-exiting' control
//    revised on: 24 MAY 2007 -- sets the 'NMI-exiting' control
//    revised on: 21 JUL 2008 -- for Linux kernel version 2.6.26.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>    // for init_module()
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>    // for create_proc_read_entry()
#include <linux/fs.h>        // for struct file_operations
#include <asm/io.h>        // for virt_to_phys()
#include <asm/uaccess.h>    // for copy_from_user()
#include <linux/slab.h> // for init_module()
#include <linux/mm.h>           // for remap_pfn_range()
#include <linux/seq_file.h>
#include "machine.h"        // for our VMCS fields
#include "myvmx.h"        // for 'regs_ia32'

#define N_ARENAS    11    // number of 64KB memory allocations
#define ARENA_LENGTH  (64<<10)    // size of each allocated memory-arena
#define IA32_VMX_BASIC               0x0480
#define IA32_VMX_PINBASED_CTLS       0x0481
#define IA32_VMX_PROCBASED_CTLS      0x0482
#define IA32_VMX_EXIT_CTLS           0x0483
#define IA32_VMX_ENTRY_CTLS          0x0484
#define IA32_VMX_MISC                0x0485
#define IA32_VMX_CR0_FIXED0          0x0486
#define IA32_VMX_CR0_FIXED1          0x0487
#define IA32_VMX_CR4_FIXED0          0x0488
#define IA32_VMX_CR4_FIXED1          0x0489
#define IA32_VMX_VMCS_ENUM           0x048A
#define IA32_VMX_PROCBASED_CTLS2     0x048B
#define IA32_VMX_EPT_VPID_CAP        0x048C
#define IA32_VMX_TRUE_PINBASED_CTLS  0x048D
#define IA32_VMX_TRUE_PROCBASED_CTLS 0x048E
#define IA32_VMX_TRUE_EXIT_CTLS      0x048F
#define IA32_VMX_TRUE_ENTRY_CTLS     0x0490
#define NUM_VMX_MSR                 (IA32_VMX_TRUE_ENTRY_CTLS - IA32_VMX_BASIC + 1) 
#define LEGACY_REACH  0x110000    // end of 'real-addressible' memory

#define PAGE_DIR_OFFSET    0x2000
#define PAGE_TBL_OFFSET    0x3000
#define IDT_KERN_OFFSET    0x4000
#define GDT_KERN_OFFSET    0x4800
#define LDT_KERN_OFFSET    0x4A00
#define TSS_KERN_OFFSET    0x4C00
#define TOS_KERN_OFFSET    0x8000
#define ISR_KERN_OFFSET    0x8000
#define __SELECTOR_TASK    0x0008
#define __SELECTOR_LDTR    0x0010
#define __SELECTOR_CODE    0x0004
#define __SELECTOR_DATA    0x000C
#define __SELECTOR_VRAM    0x0014
#define __SELECTOR_FLAT    0x001C

char modname[] = "nmiexits";
int my_major = 88;
char cpu_oem[16];
int cpu_features;
void *kmem[ N_ARENAS ];
unsigned long msr0x480[ NUM_VMX_MSR ];
unsigned long cr0, cr4;
unsigned long msr_efer;
unsigned long vmxon_region;
unsigned long guest_region;
unsigned long pgdir_region;
unsigned long pgtbl_region;
unsigned long g_IDT_region;
unsigned long g_GDT_region;
unsigned long g_LDT_region;
unsigned long g_TSS_region;
unsigned long g_TOS_region;
unsigned long g_ISR_region;

//============================================================
long my_ioctl( struct file *, unsigned int, unsigned long );
int my_release ( struct inode *inode, struct file *file );

int my_mmap( struct file *file, struct vm_area_struct *vma )
{
    unsigned long    user_virtaddr = vma->vm_start;
    unsigned long    region_length = vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start;
    unsigned long    physical_addr, pfn;
    int        i;

    // we require prescribed parameter-values from our client
    if ( user_virtaddr != 0x00000000L ) return -EINVAL;
    if ( region_length != LEGACY_REACH ) return -EINVAL;

    // let the kernel know not to try swapping out this region
    /// vma->vm_flags |= VM_RESERVED;

    // ask the kernel to add page-table entries to 'map' these arenas
    for (i = 0; i < N_ARENAS+6; i++)
        {
        int    j = i % 16;
        if ( j < 0xA ) physical_addr = virt_to_phys( kmem[ j ] );
        else    physical_addr = user_virtaddr;
        pfn = ( physical_addr >> PAGE_SHIFT );
        if ( remap_pfn_range( vma, user_virtaddr, pfn,
            ARENA_LENGTH, vma->vm_page_prot ) ) return -EAGAIN;
        user_virtaddr += ARENA_LENGTH;
        }

    // copy page-frame 0x000 to bottom of arena 0x0 (for IVT and BDA)
    memcpy( kmem[0], phys_to_virt( 0x00000 ), PAGE_SIZE );

    // copy page-frames 0x90 to 0x9F to arena 0x9 (for EBDA)    
    memcpy( kmem[9], phys_to_virt( 0x90000 ), ARENA_LENGTH );    

    return    0;    // SUCCESS
}


struct file_operations    
my_fops =    {
        owner:        THIS_MODULE,
        .unlocked_ioctl=        my_ioctl,
        mmap:        my_mmap,
        .release        =   my_release,
};

void set_CR4_vmxe( void *dummy )
{
    asm(    " mov %%cr4, %%rax     \n"\
        " bts $13, %%rax     \n"\
        " mov %%rax, %%cr4    " ::: "ax" );
}

void clear_CR4_vmxe( void *dummy )
{
    asm(    " mov %%cr4, %%rax     \n"\
        " btr $13, %%rax     \n"\
        " mov %%rax, %%cr4    " ::: "ax" );
}

static inline u64
vmx_rdmsr (u32 ecx)
{
    u32 edx, eax;

    asm volatile ("rdmsr":"=d" (edx), "=a" (eax):"c" (ecx));
    return (((u64) edx) << 32) | ((u64) eax);
}

static inline void
vmx_wrmsr (u32 ecx, u64 val)
{
    u32 edx, eax;

    edx = (u32) (val >> 32);
    eax = (u32) val;

    asm volatile ("wrmsr"::"d" (edx), "a" (eax), "c" (ecx));
}

int init_module( void )
{
    int    i, j;

    // confirm installation and show device-major number
    printk( "<1>\nInstalling \'%s\' module ", modname );
    printk( "(major=%d) \n", my_major );

    // verify processor supports Intel Virtualization Technology
    asm(    " xor     %%eax, %%eax        \n"\
        " cpuid                \n"\
        " mov    %%ebx, cpu_oem+0     \n"\
        " mov    %%edx, cpu_oem+4     \n"\
        " mov    %%ecx, cpu_oem+8     \n"\
        ::: "ax", "bx", "cx", "dx"    );
    printk( " processor is \'%s\' \n", cpu_oem );

    if ( strncmp( cpu_oem, "GenuineIntel", 12 ) == 0 )
        asm(    " mov    $1, %%eax        \n"\
            " cpuid                \n"\
            " mov    %%ecx, cpu_features    \n"\
            ::: "ax", "bx", "cx", "dx"     );
    if ( ( cpu_features & (1<<5) ) == 0 )
        {
        printk( " Virtualization Technology is unsupported \n" );
        return    -ENODEV;
        }
    else    printk( " Virtualization Technology is supported \n" );

    // read contents of the VMX-Capability Model-Specific Registers
    asm(    " xor    %%rbx, %%rbx            \n"\
        " mov    %0, %%rcx            \n"\
        "nxcap:                    \n"\
        " rdmsr                    \n"\
        " mov    %%eax, msr0x480+0(, %%rbx, 8)    \n"\
        " mov    %%edx, msr0x480+4(, %%rbx, 8)    \n"\
        " inc    %%rcx                \n"\
        " inc    %%rbx                \n"\
        " cmp    $17, %%rbx            \n"\
        " jb    nxcap                \n"\
        :: "i" (IA32_VMX_BASIC) : "ax", "bx", "cx", "dx"     );

    // preserve the initial values in relevant system registers
    asm( " mov %%cr0, %%rax \n mov %%rax, cr0 " ::: "ax" );
    asm( " mov %%cr4, %%rax \n mov %%rax, cr4 " ::: "ax" );

    asm(    " mov    %0, %%ecx        \n"\
        " rdmsr                \n"\
        " mov    %%eax, msr_efer+0    \n"\
        " mov    %%edx, msr_efer+4    \n"\
        :: "i" (MSR_EFER) : "ax", "cx", "dx" );

    // allocate page-aligned blocks of non-pageable kernel memory
    for (i = 0; i < N_ARENAS; i++)
        {
        kmem[ i ] = kmalloc( ARENA_LENGTH, GFP_KERNEL );
        if ( kmem[ i ] == NULL )
            {
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++) kfree( kmem[ j ] );
            return    -ENOMEM;
            }
        else    memset( kmem[ i ], 0x00, ARENA_LENGTH );
        }

    // assign usages to allocated kernel memory areas
    vmxon_region = virt_to_phys( kmem[ 10 ] + 0x0000 );
    guest_region = virt_to_phys( kmem[ 10 ] + 0x1000 );
    pgdir_region = virt_to_phys( kmem[ 10 ] + PAGE_DIR_OFFSET );
    pgtbl_region = virt_to_phys( kmem[ 10 ] + PAGE_TBL_OFFSET );
    g_IDT_region = virt_to_phys( kmem[ 10 ] + IDT_KERN_OFFSET );
    g_GDT_region = virt_to_phys( kmem[ 10 ] + GDT_KERN_OFFSET );
    g_LDT_region = virt_to_phys( kmem[ 10 ] + LDT_KERN_OFFSET );
    g_TSS_region = virt_to_phys( kmem[ 10 ] + TSS_KERN_OFFSET );
    g_TOS_region = virt_to_phys( kmem[ 10 ] + TOS_KERN_OFFSET );
    g_ISR_region = virt_to_phys( kmem[ 10 ] + ISR_KERN_OFFSET );

    return    register_chrdev( my_major, modname, &my_fops );
}

void cleanup_module( void )
{
    int    i;

    smp_call_function( clear_CR4_vmxe, NULL, 1 );
    clear_CR4_vmxe( NULL );

    unregister_chrdev( my_major, modname );

    for (i = 0; i < N_ARENAS; i++) kfree( kmem[ i ] );

    printk( "<1>Removing \'%s\' module\n", modname );
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

unsigned short    _gdtr[ 5 ], _idtr[ 5 ];
unsigned int    _eax, _ebx, _ecx, _edx, _esp, _ebp, _esi, _edi;
int        retval = -1;

int    nmiints = 0;
int    extints = 0;

regs_ia32    vm;

long my_ioctl( struct file *file, unsigned int count, unsigned long buf)
{
    unsigned long   *gdt, *ldt, *idt;
    unsigned int    *pgtbl, *pgdir, *tss, phys_addr = 0;
    signed long     desc = 0;
    int             i, j;

    // sanity check: we require the client-process to pass an
    // exact amount of data representing CPU's register-state
    if ( count != sizeof( regs_ia32 ) ) return -EINVAL;

    // reinitialize the Virtual Machine Control Stuctures
    memset( phys_to_virt( vmxon_region ), 0x00, PAGE_SIZE );
    memset( phys_to_virt( guest_region ), 0x00, PAGE_SIZE );
    memcpy( phys_to_virt( vmxon_region ), msr0x480, 4 );
    memcpy( phys_to_virt( guest_region ), msr0x480, 4 );

    // initialize our guest-task's page-table and page-directory
    pgtbl = (unsigned int*)phys_to_virt( pgtbl_region );
    for (i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
        switch ( i ) {
            case 0: case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4:
            case 5: case 6: case 7: case 8: case 9:
                phys_addr = virt_to_phys( kmem[ i ] ); break;
            case 10: case 11: case 12: case 13: case 14: case 15:
                phys_addr = i * ARENA_LENGTH; break;
            case 16:
                phys_addr = virt_to_phys( kmem[ 0 ] ); break;
            case 17:
                phys_addr = virt_to_phys( kmem[ 10 ] ); break;
        }
        for (j = 0; j < 16; j++)
            pgtbl[ i*16 + j ] = phys_addr + (j << PAGE_SHIFT) + 7;
    }
    pgdir = (unsigned int*)phys_to_virt( pgdir_region );
    pgdir[ 0 ] = (unsigned int)pgtbl_region + 7;

    // copy the client's virtual-machine register-values
    if ( copy_from_user( &vm, (void*)buf, count ) ) return -EFAULT;
    guest_ES_selector = vm.es;
    guest_CS_selector = vm.cs;
    guest_SS_selector = vm.ss;
    guest_DS_selector = vm.ds;
    guest_FS_selector = vm.fs;
    guest_GS_selector = vm.gs;
    _eax = vm.eax;
    _ebx = vm.ebx;
    _ecx = vm.ecx;
    _edx = vm.edx;
    _ebp = vm.ebp;
    _esi = vm.esi;
    _edi = vm.edi;
    guest_RSP = vm.esp;
    guest_RIP = vm.eip;
    guest_RFLAGS = vm.eflags;
    guest_RFLAGS |= (1 << 17);    // VM=1 (for Virtual-8086 mode)
    guest_RFLAGS |= (1 <<  1);    // it's essential to set bit #1
    // setup other guest-state fields (for Virtual-8086 mode)
    guest_ES_base = (guest_ES_selector << 4);
    guest_CS_base = (guest_CS_selector << 4);
    guest_SS_base = (guest_SS_selector << 4);
    guest_DS_base = (guest_DS_selector << 4);
    guest_FS_base = (guest_FS_selector << 4);
    guest_GS_base = (guest_GS_selector << 4);
    guest_ES_limit = 0xFFFF;
    guest_CS_limit = 0xFFFF;
    guest_SS_limit = 0xFFFF;
    guest_DS_limit = 0xFFFF;
    guest_FS_limit = 0xFFFF;
    guest_GS_limit = 0xFFFF;
    guest_ES_access_rights = 0xF3;
    guest_CS_access_rights = 0xF3;
    guest_SS_access_rights = 0xF3;
    guest_DS_access_rights = 0xF3;
    guest_FS_access_rights = 0xF3;
    guest_GS_access_rights = 0xF3;

    guest_CR0 = 0x80000031;
    guest_CR4 = 0x00002011;
    guest_CR3 = pgdir_region;
    guest_VMCS_link_pointer_full = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    guest_VMCS_link_pointer_high = 0xFFFFFFFF;

    guest_IDTR_base = LEGACY_REACH + IDT_KERN_OFFSET;
    guest_GDTR_base = LEGACY_REACH + GDT_KERN_OFFSET;
    guest_LDTR_base = LEGACY_REACH + LDT_KERN_OFFSET;
    guest_TR_base   = LEGACY_REACH + TSS_KERN_OFFSET;
    guest_IDTR_limit = (256 * 8) - 1;
    guest_GDTR_limit = (3 * 8) - 1;
    guest_LDTR_limit = (4 * 8) - 1;
    guest_TR_limit   = (26 * 4) + 0x20 + 0x2000;
    guest_LDTR_access_rights = 0x82;
    guest_TR_access_rights   = 0x8B;
    guest_LDTR_selector = __SELECTOR_LDTR;
    guest_TR_selector   = __SELECTOR_TASK;

    // provisionally initialize our guest-task's LDTR
    ldt = (unsigned long*)phys_to_virt( g_LDT_region );
    ldt[ __SELECTOR_CODE >> 3 ] = 0x00CF9B000000FFFF;
    ldt[ __SELECTOR_DATA >> 3 ] = 0x00CF93000000FFFF;
    ldt[ __SELECTOR_VRAM >> 3 ] = 0x0000920B8000FFFF;
    ldt[ __SELECTOR_FLAT >> 3 ] = 0x008F92000000FFFF;
    // Adjust the CODE and DATA descriptors here
    desc = LEGACY_REACH + ISR_KERN_OFFSET;
    desc <<= 16;
    desc &= 0x000000FFFFFF0000;
    ldt[ __SELECTOR_CODE >> 3 ] |= desc;
    ldt[ __SELECTOR_DATA >> 3 ] |= desc;

    // initialize our guest-task's GDTR
    gdt = (unsigned long*)phys_to_virt( g_GDT_region );
    desc = 0x00008B0000000000;
    desc |= (guest_TR_base << 32)&0xFF00000000000000;
    desc |= (guest_TR_base << 16)&0x000000FFFFFF0000;
    desc |= (guest_TR_limit & 0xFFFF);
    gdt[ __SELECTOR_TASK >> 3 ] = desc;
    desc = 0x0000820000000000;
    desc |= ( guest_LDTR_base << 32)&0xFF00000000000000;
    desc |= ( guest_LDTR_base << 16)&0x000000FFFFFF0000;
    desc |= ( guest_LDTR_limit & 0xFFFF );
    gdt[ __SELECTOR_LDTR >> 3 ] = desc;

    // initialize our guest's IDT
    idt = (unsigned long*)phys_to_virt( g_IDT_region );
    desc = 0;        // offset-address for GPF isr
    desc &= 0x00000000FFFFFFFF;
    desc |= (desc << 32);
    desc &= 0xFFFF00000000FFFF;
    desc |= ( __SELECTOR_CODE << 16);
    desc |= 0x00008E0000000000;
    idt[ 13 ] = desc;

    // initialize our guest's Task-State Segment
    tss = (unsigned int*)phys_to_virt( g_TSS_region );
    tss[ 1 ] = TOS_KERN_OFFSET;
    tss[ 2 ] = __SELECTOR_DATA;
    tss[ 25 ] = 0x00880000;
    tss[ guest_TR_limit >> 2 ] = 0xFF;

    //----------------------------------------------------
    // initialize the global variables for the host state
    //----------------------------------------------------
    asm(" mov %%cr0, %%rax \n mov %%rax, host_CR0 " ::: "ax" );
    asm(" mov %%cr4, %%rax \n mov %%rax, host_CR4 " ::: "ax" );
    asm(" mov %%cr3, %%rax \n mov %%rax, host_CR3 " ::: "ax" );
    asm(" str host_TR_selector ");
    asm(" mov %es, host_ES_selector ");    
    asm(" mov %cs, host_CS_selector ");    
    asm(" mov %ss, host_SS_selector ");    
    asm(" mov %ds, host_DS_selector ");    
    asm(" mov %fs, host_FS_selector ");    
    asm(" mov %gs, host_GS_selector ");    
    asm(" sgdt _gdtr \n sidt _idtr ");
    host_GDTR_base = *(unsigned long*)( _gdtr+1 );
    host_IDTR_base = *(unsigned long*)( _idtr+1 );

    gdt = (unsigned long*)host_GDTR_base;
    desc = gdt[ (host_TR_selector >> 3) + 0 ];
    host_TR_base = ((desc >> 16)&0x00FFFFFF)|((desc >> 32)&0xFF000000);
    desc = gdt[ (host_TR_selector >> 3) + 1 ];
    desc <<= 48;    // maneuver to insure 'canonical' address
    host_TR_base |= (desc >> 16)&0xFFFFFFFF00000000;

    asm(    " mov    $0x174, %%ecx            \n"\
        " rdmsr                    \n"\
        " mov    %%eax, host_SYSENTER_CS        \n"\
        " inc    %%ecx                \n"\
        " rdmsr                    \n"\
        " mov    %%eax, host_SYSENTER_ESP+0     \n"\
        " mov    %%edx, host_SYSENTER_ESP+4     \n"\
        " inc    %%ecx                \n"\
        " rdmsr                    \n"\
        " mov    %%eax, host_SYSENTER_EIP+0    \n"\
        " mov    %%edx, host_SYSENTER_EIP+4     \n"\
        ::: "ax", "cx", "dx" );

    asm(    " mov    %0, %%ecx        \n"\
        " rdmsr                \n"\
        " mov    %%eax, host_FS_base+0     \n"\
        " mov    %%edx, host_FS_base+4    \n"\
        :: "i" (0xC0000100) : "ax", "cx", "dx" );

    asm(    " mov    %0, %%ecx        \n"\
        " rdmsr                \n"\
        " mov    %%eax, host_GS_base+0     \n"\
        " mov    %%edx, host_GS_base+4    \n"\
        :: "i" (0xC0000101) : "ax", "cx", "dx" );

    //------------------------------------------------------
    // initialize the global variables for the VMX controls
    //------------------------------------------------------
    control_VMX_pin_based = msr0x480[ 1 ];
    control_VMX_cpu_based = msr0x480[ 2 ];
    control_VM_exit_controls = msr0x480[ 3 ];
    control_VM_entry_controls = msr0x480[ 4 ];
    control_VMX_pin_based |= (1 << 0);    // exit on interrupts    
    control_VMX_pin_based |= (1 << 3);    // NMI-exiting      
    control_VMX_cpu_based |= (1 << 7) | (1 << 29); // Hlt + Monitor exit

    control_pagefault_errorcode_match = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    control_VM_exit_controls |= (1 << 9);    // exit to 64-bit host

    control_CR0_mask = 0x80000021;
    control_CR4_mask = 0x00002000;
    control_CR0_shadow = 0x80000021;
    control_CR4_shadow = 0x00002000;
    control_CR3_target_count = 2;
    control_CR3_target0 = guest_CR3;    // guest's directory
    control_CR3_target1 = host_CR3;        // host's directory

// initialize our counters for NMIs and external interrupts
nmiints = 0;
extints = 0;

    // enable virtual machine extensions (bit 13 in CR4)
    set_CR4_vmxe( NULL );    
    smp_call_function( set_CR4_vmxe, NULL, 1 );

    //---------------------
    // launch the guest VM
    //---------------------
    asm volatile ("    .type  my_vmm, @function    \n"\
        " pushfq                \n"\
        " push    %rax                \n"\
        " push    %rbx                \n"\
        " push    %rcx                \n"\
        " push    %rdx                \n"\
        " push    %rbp                \n"\
        " push    %rsi                \n"\
        " push    %rdi                \n"\
        " push    %r11                \n"\
        "                    \n"\
        " lea    my_vmm, %rax            \n"\
        "                    \n"\
        " mov    %rax, host_RIP            \n"\
        " mov    %rsp, host_RSP            \n"\
        "                    \n"\
        " vmxon    vmxon_region            \n"\
        " jc    fail                \n"\
        " jz    over                \n"\
        "                    \n"\
        " movl    $1, retval            \n"\
        " vmclear guest_region            \n"\
        "                    \n"\
        " movl    $2, retval            \n"\
        " vmptrld guest_region            \n"\
        "                    \n"\
        " movl    $3, retval            \n"\
        "                    \n"\
        " xor    %rdx, %rdx            \n"\
        " mov    elements, %rcx            \n"\
        "nxwr:                    \n"\
        " mov    machine+0(%rdx), %rax        \n"\
        " mov    machine+8(%rdx), %rbx        \n"\
        " vmwrite (%rbx), %rax            \n"\
        " add    $16, %rdx            \n"\
        " loop    nxwr                \n"\
        "                    \n"\
        " movl     $4, retval            \n"\
        " mov    _eax, %eax            \n"\
        " mov    _ebx, %ebx            \n"\
        " mov    _ecx, %ecx            \n"\
        " mov    _edx, %edx            \n"\
        " mov    _ebp, %ebp            \n"\
        " mov    _esi, %esi            \n"\
        " mov    _edi, %edi            \n"\
        "  vmlaunch                \n"\
        " movl     $5, retval            \n"\
        " jmp    read                \n"\
        "my_vmm:                \n"\
        "                    \n"\
        " mov    %eax, _eax            \n"\
        " mov    %ebx, _ebx            \n"\
        " mov    %ecx, _ecx            \n"\
        " mov    %edx, _edx            \n"\
        " mov    %ebp, _ebp            \n"\
        " mov    %esi, _esi            \n"\
        " mov    %edi, _edi            \n"\
        "read:                    \n"\
        " xor    %rdx, %rdx            \n"\
        " mov    rocount, %rcx            \n"\
        "nxrd:                    \n"\
        " mov    results+0(%rdx), %rax        \n"\
        " mov    results+8(%rdx), %rbx        \n"\
        " vmread %rax, (%rbx)            \n"\
        " add    $16, %rdx            \n"\
        " loop    nxrd                \n"\
        "                    \n"\
        " cmpl    $0, info_vmexit_reason        \n"\
        " je    was_nmi                \n"\
        "                    \n"\
        " cmpl    $1, info_vmexit_reason        \n"\
        " je    was_extint            \n"\
        "                    \n"\
        " jmp    over                \n"\
        "                    \n"\
        "was_nmi:                \n"\
        " incl    nmiints                \n"\
/*        " int    $0x02                \n"\
*/        " jmp    resume_guest            \n"\
        "                    \n"\
        "was_extint:                \n"\
        " sti                    \n"\
        " incl    extints                \n"\
        "                    \n"\
        "resume_guest:                \n"\
        " mov    _eax, %eax            \n"\
        " mov    _ebx, %ebx            \n"\
        " mov    _ecx, %ecx            \n"\
        " mov    _edx, %edx            \n"\
        " mov    _ebp, %ebp            \n"\
        " mov    _esi, %esi            \n"\
        " mov    _edi, %edi            \n"\
        "  vmresume                \n"\
        "                    \n"\
        " movl  $-1, retval            \n"\
        "over:                    \n"\
        " vmxoff                \n"\
        "fail:                    \n"\
        " pop    %r11                \n"\
        " pop    %rdi                \n"\
        " pop    %rsi                \n"\
        " pop    %rbp                \n"\
        " pop    %rdx                \n"\
        " pop    %rcx                \n"\
        " pop    %rbx                \n"\
        " pop    %rax                \n"\
        " popfq                    \n"\
        );

    // show why the VMentry failed, or else why the VMexit occurred    
    printk( "\n VM-instruction error: %d  ", info_vminstr_error );
    printk( " Exit Reason: %d \n", info_vmexit_reason );
    printk( " VMexit-interruption-information: %08X \n",
                    info_vmexit_interrupt_information );
    printk( " VMexit-interruption-error-code:  %08X \n",
            info_vmexit_interrupt_error_code  );

    if (retval >= 0) {
        retval = info_vmexit_reason;
    }
    // display the number of external interruption-exits
    printk( "\n" );
    printk( " number of external interrupts = %d \n", extints );
    printk( " number of non-maskable interrupts = %d \n", nmiints );

    // copy the client's virtual-machine register-values
    vm.eflags = (unsigned int)guest_RFLAGS;
    vm.eip = (unsigned int)guest_RIP;    
    vm.esp = (unsigned int)guest_RSP;    
    vm.eax = _eax;
    vm.ebx = _ebx;
    vm.ecx = _ecx;
    vm.edx = _edx;
    vm.ebp = _ebp;
    vm.esi = _esi;
    vm.edi = _edi;
    vm.es  = guest_ES_selector;
    vm.cs  = guest_CS_selector;
    vm.ss  = guest_SS_selector;
    vm.ds  = guest_DS_selector;
    vm.fs  = guest_FS_selector;
    vm.gs  = guest_GS_selector;
    if ( copy_to_user( (void*)buf, &vm, count ) ) return -EFAULT;

    return    retval;
}

int my_release ( struct inode *inode, struct file *file )
{
    pr_info("Calling %s\n", __func__);
/*
    smp_call_function( clear_CR4_vmxe, NULL, 1 );
    clear_CR4_vmxe( NULL );
*/
    retval = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

By testing above code, with delay.cpp, I found the very first time VMlaunch will fail with VMX instruction error of 8 (invalid host state), all the subsequent VMX operation will be fine.

After debugging it, i found it is related to where to set and clear VMXE (bit13) in CR4.

If setting VMXE bit in init_module, the VM could be launched well every time, no error of 8.

Then, if clearing VMXE bit in my_release, the VMX operation will fail every time (so i commented out that operation).

I must miss something important about the sequence of entering VMX root operation.

My testing environment is VMware WS, and a bare-metal Ubuntu Linux host.
I tested in SMP host, and non-SMP host, got the same result.

Comment: It seems like you should [reduce the problem a bit](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Dumping source files with head comments seems like it could be improved.

Comment: OK, but i thought, i should keep the head comments, since i mostly based on this code (and the declarations). And I would like to save others' time, if they don't want to go the link to understand what this code does. I would accept your comments when i post my own codes. Thx.

Comment: I don’t understand the question... if VMXE is clear, vmxon will fail. If VMXE is set, but vmxon fails, there is some other problem that doesn’t have anything to do with VMXE.

Comment: I got confused at all. The issue happens when run VMLaunch for the very first time, all subsequent VMLaunch/vmresume work well.  For example, I compiled the VM from delay.cpp to delay, and load nmiexits.ko, mknod /dev/vmm c 88 0. Now run ./delay, it fails with -1 (dmesg shows instruction error of 8), then run ./delay again, the VM will be ran (delayed for a while), and vmexit with CPUID or others.  This is the first case.  For the second case, where clear VMXE is moved to my_release, recompile the module, repeat above steps, it will fail every time with instruction error of 8.  Very confusing.